# Redirect http request to https requests in linux server

Tags: linux, apache, http, https, centos

my app is using the port number 8443 and I am looking for configuration or steps to redirect http://example.com:8443 requests to https://example.com:8443.

and I'm not sure whether httpd(apache) support any other ports apart from 80 and 443.

thanks and appreciate any quick help on this.

Comment: This is a bit odd ... 1. the apache http server can use any ports you configure it to use. 2. it is unclear, how your _app_ can use a port, except if it contains an own,buildin http server in which case you won't need apache. 3. you cannot server http and https protocols on the same port, that does not make sense.

Comment: What is your app? If it provides its own http server through its framework/library, you will need to consult the documentation on how to enable https. The standard way is to simply use a front-facing http server (such as apache as you noted; nginx is another option) that runs on both port 80 and 443 (i.e. http/https) and use that to reverse proxy to your application server.